# What is a two part xml tag?

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to read in some xml and want to find the tag names.
For example if I read `<dc:title>`, I want to get "title".
Can someone tell me what the "dc" part is and what the "title" part is?

I'm using Python and when I iterate over the nodes and print out
`node.tag`, it returns "{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}title". I really don't know what the url stuff is or why it's returning with my node tag.

Comment: This is an XML namespace declaration. W3C specifications (your go-to for all things XML): http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I found this and it seems to work.

```
item.tag.split("}")[1][0:]
```